# Why does my running under xelatex have a 10 seconds pause?

Tags: xetex, pdftex

When I run the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Hello world!
\end{document}
```

with the iso version of Tex live 2017 using `xelatex`, my running gets about a 10 seconds pause with this warning on command line:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99998 (TeX Live 2017/W32TeX) (preloaded format=xelatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.10> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
(c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
```

and then automatically  continues. I don't have this problem with `pdflatex`. Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: Normally this should only happen once after a change in the fonts -- it means that the cache is recreated -- if you get it all the time you could try `fc-cache -f` on a command line.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: Yes. I run a file in which I didn't a font and then this problem appeared. I did what you said, but i got this message: `C:/texlive/2017/texmf-var/fonts/cache\d031bbba323fd9e5b47e0ee5a0353f11-x86.cache
-7: Permission denied`. I have a windows 7 machine.

Comment: Check if the `permission denied` was only tempory: close everything restart the computer and then try again. If the problem persists you will have to find out who is denying the access. If fc-cache can't create the cache, xelatex probably can't neither, and then it is not wonder that it tries it again at every compilation.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I tried `fc-cache.exe -v -f -r` on the command line and now it's Ok. Thank you.

Comment: OK. I added an answer to get the question from the unanswered list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get this pause when xetex is recreating the font cache. It normally does it if you added or changed fonts. In TeXlive 2017 and a current miktex the pause should happen only for one compilation.

If the problem doesn't go away you should run on a command line

```
fc-cache -f
```

(force) or

```
fc-cache -r
```

(really force)

perhaps along with `-v` which would either repair the font cache or at least give some message to get a clue why the cache can not be created correctly.

In TeX Live 2016 one should (due to a bug) call `fc-cache -f` always when fonts have been changed.